# Selenium: Get the string out of a email textfield/textbox

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get an email string out of an email textbox which was recently entered.

I'm doing automation tests with selenium and to confirm that the correct string was entered into the textbox, I want to recheck it before it goes on to the password textbox.

I saw a lot of examples here but the most are either `getText();` (which seems to not work anymore)  or `getAttribute("Value");`.

I debugged it, and the `checkText` gives always Null.

What im currently having is this code:

```
    public static void SendKeysElement(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {

        IWebElement Field = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(selector));
        Field.SendKeys("example@example.com");

        string checkText = Field.GetAttribute("Value");

        if (checkText != "example@example.com")
        {
           Console.WriteLine("String is wrong");
        }
        else
        {
        ConsoleWriteLine("String is correct");    
        }
    }
```

Here is the inspect of that textbox, while the email string was entered.
The first thing I notice is, that the entered string in the email textbox is not displayed in the inspect.

[image: Picture of the inspect]

The webpage is being written with .NET using a blazor template.

Comment: Update the code with `textToType` and xpath that you've used, you should first click on password field and than you can have this validation.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that validation too. And entered a password. But still nothing. 

What do you mean with "update with textToType"?

Comment: Oh it was a mistake by me. Instead of "textToType" it should be only the email string. I corrected it. But still checkText getting Null

Comment: I think `.GetAttribute("Value")` should be `GetAttribute("value");`

Comment: omg.. you got it right! Thanks!

Comment: I have given that as a solution below, now we can close this ticket.

Comment: As always thanks cruise! You helped me a few times already :)

Comment: No problem beardy !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
.GetAttribute("Value")
```

try this :

```
.GetAttribute("value");
```

Note that, **attribute type** is case sensitive.